# Windows 8.x making all files open in desktop mode

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-registry

When I setup Windows 8 I install a start menu system to make tasks smoother. However, I would like a one click script to make ALL files like images open with the Windows Image Viewer in desktop mode.

Is there a registry hack I could use to make that happen or a way I can monitor registry changes and save them as I set defaults? This way I can export them out and create a registry script.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

1. Press Windows Key + <kbd>R</kbd> combination on keyboard and type `regedit` in Run dialog box. Press *OK*.
2. Navigate to the following location:

   ```
   HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\image\shell\edit\command
   ```
3. In the *right pane*, double-click on the *Default* string, you’ll find the command to *Microsoft Paint*( ie "%systemroot%\system32\mspaint.exe" "%1").
4. Change the *Value* data to the location of your desired software. For example, if you want to set *Windows Photo Viewer* as default image editing software, put this:

   ```
   "rundll32.exe %SystemRoot%\System32\shimgvw.dll, ImageView_Fullscreen" "%1"
   ```
5. Now close the *Registry Editor* and restart the system to get results.

Answer (score 0):

**NO, there is no registry hack to do it.** You have to manually set all file associations *the ones you prefer* and select a desktop program to open it by default.

However, if you have Windows 8.1, you should have upgraded to Windows 8.1 Update 1, as this update automatically does it for you! But now you are out of luck!